# Jsoup (Find Element)

Tags: java, jsoup

Help solve the problem, it is necessary to pull some data from Wikipedia, I'll show them in the picture below:

[image: data from wiki]

In the page code, these data are here:

[image: code wiki]

How to get this data? to do this is by using jsoup.

I tried to do it like this:

```
 System.out.println(doc.select("div.mw-body-content > p ").first().text());
```

But the problem is that it so happens that this is not the first

in code, and the second is for something:

[image: desired data]

Comment: how to get the data as shown in the last picture? need to pull information from the second tag <p>

Comment: Try with `select().get(1)`, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the parent `div` by its ID (which should be unique):

   ```
   Elements parent = doc.select("div#mw-body-content");
   ```
2. Get all `p` tags in this element (including the second one you would like to have):

   ```
   Elements paragraphs = parent.getElementsByTag("p");
   ```
3. Take the second of it:

   ```
   String text = paragraphs.get(1).text();
   ```