# BeautifulSoup find specific td data-sort="name"

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hy, is there a similar way to

> soup.findAll('div', class_="cities")

only to with the data-sort  attribute?

I don´t know like

> soup.findAll('td', data-sort_="citiesVillage")

i like to find only the rows with a specific data-sort name.

thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23978520/1531971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup.findAll('td', attrs={'data-sort': 'citiesVillage'})
```

Comment: Thanks, Muhika Thomas! Works fine.

Comment: awesome. happy hunting